# How can i set icon on custom plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have already create my custom plugin but wordpress show me default icon in dashboard. So how can i change plugin icon?
i have try to :

```html
<? /*
      Plugin Name: Rawin Plugin
      Description: Plugin for testing purpose 
      Version: 1
      Author: Rahul Dabhi
      Author URI: 
     */
?>
```

can i change in this section? please answer me as soon as possible.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a close look at add_menu_page hook, it provides argument to supply with icon url

```
<?php 
add_menu_page( 
    $page_title, 
    $menu_title, 
    $capability, 
    $menu_slug, 
    $function, 
    $icon_url, 
    $position 
);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

```
add_menu_page(
    __('Poll','menu-test'), 
    __('Poll','menu-test'), 
    'manage_options', 
    'manage-polls', 
    'poll_page',
    'plugins_folder Or Theme folder url/icon.png' 
);
```